# Need to change CSS div positioning based on site section

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I am sorry if this has already been answered elsewhere, but I am having a really hard time finding anything relevant.

The site: http://www.jamesaslett.club/

I am trying to find a way to make the line underneath the menu (.lava-nav) always follow the active section (in the same way that the section text changes to black). I already have it working on hover, but I just can't figure out the best solution to get it to work for current active section.

Below is the code I am using the add and remove the class that changes the font text to black; should I be doing something similar here?

```
function afterLoadCallback(anchorLink) {
    $("a", "#topnav").removeClass("activenav");
    $("a[href=#"+anchorLink+"]", "#topnav").addClass("activenav");
};
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi here is working example of what you need:
http://codepen.io/xszaboj/pen/gmMjGg?editors=0010

HTML:

```
<header>
    <nav class="main-nav nav" id="header">
        <ul class="topnav" id="topnav">
            <li><a href="#music" data-left="11.4%" data-width="50px" class="btn">MUSIC</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery" data-left="20.7%" data-width="74px" class="btn">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#video" data-left="32.5%" data-width="50px" class="btn">VIDEO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#home" class="btn btn-hide activenav" data-left="42.2%" data-width="125px">MASK OF JUDAS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gigs" data-left="60.7%" data-width="41px" class="btn">GIGS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#merch" data-left="67.5%" data-width="59px" class="btn">MERCH</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" data-left="77.5%" data-width="71px" class="btn">CONTACT</a></li>
            <div class="lava-nav"</div>
        </ul>
        <div><a href="index.html#home" class="nav-text">MASK OF JUDAS</a></div>
        <div class="burger">
            <button class="hamburger hamburger--3dx" type="button">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">
                    <span class="hamburger-box">
                        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </button>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Here you can see that I've added data- attributes that are then used in javascript code.

Javascript:

```
function setSlider(element){
  var data = {
    left: element.attr("data-left"),
    width: element.attr("data-width")
  };
  $(".lava-nav").css("left", data.left).css("width", data.width);
}

$("#topnav").on("mouseover","li", function(){
  var dataElement = $(this).find("a");
  setSlider(dataElement);
})

$("#topnav").on("mouseleave", function(){
  console.log("leave")
  var active = $(".activenav").first();
  setSlider(active);
})

$("#topnav").on("click", "a", function(){
  $(".activenav").first().removeClass("activenav");
  $(this).addClass("activenav")
})
```

Here, on mouseover event load the data- attributes and move slider accordingly.
(so I removed css that did this before completely). And then there is also on mouseleave event that loads slider position (from data- attr) based on activenav class. In order to make slider "stick" to active position.

CSS same I've just removed these: `#topnav li:nth-child(1):hover ~ .lava-nav`

Comment: This works so well! One more thing though, is there a way to make the attributes change when using the mouse scroll wheel to move through the sections, as per the black text?

Comment: fullPage has afterLoad callback, so just extract on click callback into common function and call that function within that.